# SMS or Email for Firebase App Invite iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, invite

When creating an App invite, will the dialog box give the user the choice of SMS or Email invite for a friend?  I want the SMS, if so is there any additional set up or security needed to access the contact list and get a SMS message number?  Any additional info on advanced options for new Firebase App Invite would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable GoogleSignIn, and google sign in handles all the security needed to access the user contact list (currently the invitations are only supported this way...